character encoding in redis protocol
I am trying to write a simple redis type key-value server in java. I am following RESP protocol, so writing a parser for it.
I have a query regarding it. Java's default charset is UTF-8. Client can send data with different encodings. In resp protocol documentation, I dont see specific character encoding mentioned. So while parsing incoming byte stream, how does a redis server implementation understand it without knowing the encoding format?

anything wrong in this question to deserve a downvote?

The contents of the strings, that RESP returns, are bytes, so you would normally use the same decoder as the encoder you used to encode the string in the first place.
If you are talking about responses such as "OK" and etc. then UTF8 would suffice.

their doc says "RESP is a binary protocol that uses control sequences encoded in standard ASCII." It's binary, as I would expect from any protocol who learned mistakes from the 90s. End of story.

Character encodings are mainly used for character representation; they are just different ways to represent bytes. For example, ASCII encoding represents each byte as a character, while UTF-8 represents 1 to 4 bytes as a single character, depending on the language. For persistence purposes, information is stored as bytes. The only difference might be the endianness (how the bytes are read, e.g., from left to right or right to left). A Redis server can calculate the hash value of bytes and sort them in its ordered data structure. Redis simply stores the bytes as provided and returns them as is when you read them, so why bother representing them?
As you can see, when you access your data using the redis-client executable, the redis-client represents the data as a \x string, which is simply a representation of bytes.
